# Calling php files (custom login & register) in header of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have files called login.php and register.php
I am using roots theme
When I use them as template they work fine
But I don't want to create it as a page I want to call it in header 
I have called it in header-top-navbar.php as

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/login.php">Login</a>
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/register.php">Register</a>
```

but it getting url as
http:...site-name/wp-content/themes/xyz/login.php

I want it as any normal page
http:..sitename/login

So is it possible?

Comment: You're going to want to use the hooks that allow you modify the standard wp-interface (which is actually fairly customizable). [Check out a tutorial like this.](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-a-custom-wordpress-login-page/) And here's an [article from the codex about customizing registration forms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)

Comment: I have created form for login and registeration for frontend and I don't want to store it in wp_users table  so I have created anoter table.My question is url getting different otherwise form working fine

Answer (score 0):

That would be built-in. Visit Settings -> Permalinks.

Have a read at [Using_Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for additional info if necessary.

Comment: It is for pages created using wordpress.Here my question is different